# mysql delete and foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm deleting selected rows from both table in MYSQL, the two tables have foreign keys.

```
DELETE d,b
  FROM A as b
  INNER JOIN B as d on b.bid=d.bid WHERE b.name LIKE '%xxxx%';
```

MYSQL complains about foreign keys even though I'm trying to delete from both tables:

```
Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
fails (`yyy/d`, CONSTRAINT `fk_d_bid` FOREIGN KEY (`bid`) REFERENCES 
`b` (`bid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

what's the best solution here to delete from both table?

Answer (score 6):

Change this constraint to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` -- which means that if a row is deleted, then any "child" rows will be automatically deleted as well.

Of course take good care of using CASCADE -- only use it when necessary. If you're overzealous with it, and accidentally do a well-placed DELETE, it might end up deleting half of your database. :)

See [documentation on foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do

If you can't change the table structure, then you could use 2 statements, the first with a sub-select

delete from B where bid IN (select bid from A where name like '%xxxx%');

delete from A where name like '%xxxx%';

Comment: great idea, but I got You can't specify target table 'B' for update in FROM clause